# Why chkdsk stuck here for few minutes eventhough with 0 bad sectors?

Tags: chkdsk

I performed chkdsk on F drive, i find it stuck for few minutes
before it goes smoothly:

[image]

At red mark, it stuck about 20-30 mins.

chkdsk on another drives went smoothly.

Why chkdsk stuck here for few minutes eventhough with 0 bad sectors?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YO9MmCr.jpg

Comment: Its possible it was waiting for the drive to respond, check the SMART data on the drive.

Comment: It told you all was well at 144 files and then went on to complete. 487 files plus wrapping up the checking. It appears to be normal.